# How to parse JSON from request in nodeJS? By default methods (without Express etc. packgs)

Tags: node.js

### So client-side-js just send POST with JSON object

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/onadd',
    data: addJsonObj.toJSON,
    success: function(){
        console.log("Task added!", data);
    }
});
```

---

### to my nodeJS server.

I see my incoming request on nodeJS server.
So how can I parse JSON object from request on my nodeJS server?
Need smth like that:

```
if(request.method == 'POST' && request.url == '/onadd'){
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(request.body);  //can't parse JSON here!(
    console.log(jsonObj.task);   
    console.log('hoorayyyy!!!!!!');  //got this!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `dataType` like @Matthieu suggested:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/onadd',
    data: JSON.stringify(addJsonObj),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        console.log('Task added!', data);
    }
});
```

You also need to stream the request body like so:

```
if(request.method == 'POST' && request.url == '/onadd'){
    var json = '';
    request.on('data', function (chunk){
        json += chunk.toString('utf8');
    });
    request.on('end', function (){
       console.log(json);
       var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
       console.log(jsonObj.task);
    });
}
```

Comment: undefined:0
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @Spacemaster what does the `console.log` I just added say?

Comment: @Spacemaster In the front-end log what ``addJsonObj.toJSON`` is. Perhaps that isn't what you meant to send.

Comment: So I sended this JSON object {
        isCompleted: fixed,
        task: task,
        date: dateStr
    }

Comment: Is `addJsonObj.toJSON` a string or an object?

Comment: and on nodeJS side I try to get jsonObj.task

Comment: That's my method on client side js:

Comment: function addElementToArray(fixed, task, dateStr) {
    var addJsonObj = {
        isCompleted: fixed,
        task: task,
        date: dateStr
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/addTask',
        data: addJsonObj.toJSON,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
            console.log("Task added!", data);
        }
    });
  //mas.push(element);
}

Comment: @Spacemaster ``.toJSON`` is neither a valid property nor function of JavaScript objects. I updated your client-side code and it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare data type

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/onadd',
        data: addJsonObj.toJSON,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(){
            console.log("Task added!", data);
        }
});
```

Comment: No problem. i hope i helped